# Is the circle drawn on leaflet a spherical cap or a flat circle?

Tags: leaflet

I am new to GIS, so please bear with me.

I think the circle must be a flat "Web Mercator" circle, since that is the mapping, but the circle information is given as WGS84 (lat,long for center and meters for radius), so that leads me to think of it as a spherical cap.

It is my understanding that it can only be one or the other, not both.
Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Leaflet 0.7, `L.circle` was just rendered as a circle on the view port, with only the horizontal radius corresponding to the specified radius (on default Web Mercator CRS).

Starting with Leaflet 1.0, [`L.circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#circle) does a much better job in approximating a "spherical cap" (i.e. a circle on a sphere, then being projected onto Web Mercator), but it fails once it touches the latitude limits of the CRS (about +/-85 degrees latitude for Web Mercator).

You can compare `L.circle` with [Leaflet Geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) plugin (which computes a spherical cap by segments) on this Mapbox page:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-geodesy/

(it now uses Leaflet 1.0, therefore both circles overlap, except close to the poles)

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate it.

So if we are trying to see if a circle drawn on the screen contains a point (a row in the database), and the point is in lat long (converted to a Hilbert curve number), then using leaftlet 0.7, we need to convert the lat, long of the point in the database to Web Merc Number coordinates, and then convert that to a Hilbert curve number.  

However, using Leaflet 1.0, then we would leave the database value alone at lat/long (converted to Hilbert)

Do you know, at what radius would we actually see a difference between leaflet 0.7 & 1.0 greater than 1 yard?